# Pause/continue XML Parsing

Tags: ios4

Hey Friends,
I am parsing an XML and based on the contents of a particular element, an alertview is presented.
When the alert view is being displayed, I want the parser should pause until the user responses to alert. But parsing doesn't stops. In fact this alert view gets popped up when the parsing gets completed.

I don't want to use [parser abortParsing] method, as it will stop parsing completely.